# Hibernate doesn't create Table - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have spring project where I'm using hibernate. When I start project there is no change in db.

I try difrenf configurations but nothings worked.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Hibernate is configure in servlet.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<!--Data source has the database information -->
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Praktyki"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="dbusersolsoft"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="dbpassSolsoft"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Session Factory -->


<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <value>com.springapp.mvc.model</value>
    </beans:property>
    <!--<beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />-->
    <!--<beans:property name="generateDdl" value="true" />-->
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">

        <beans:props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>


</beans:bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />`

Comment: @KevinBowersox wrong syntax, I can't use that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

As per the documentation, update updates the existing schema.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) for reference.

In brief,

```
validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.

update: update the schema.

create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.

create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

auto : Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the project once before you start the project and move on.  Most applications assume the schema exists a priori when they start.

Comment: <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

should create table based on annotations. In non spring app when i configure all in hibernate.cfg.xml it worked but now I have problems.

Comment: I know what it should do; don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have followed all the procedures correctly, but still getting the error, check whether the "hibernate.dialect" is set to MySQL5Dialect in case you use the MySQL as the database.

Comment: thanks it's worked 
i don't know how mark this answer as not useful